# Event-Driven Serial Port Read MFC

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, serial-port, serial-communication

I am trying to implement an event-driven serial receive in my MFC dialog application.
I am using [this](http://www.naughter.com/serialport.html) class for access to the Win32 APIs dealing with serial ports.

I want to be notified whenever new data is received and from the description it seems like the **ReadFileEx function** (`CSerialPort::ReadEx`in the Naughter class) could help me achieve this.

> **ReadFileEx function:**
> Reads data from the specified file or input/output (I/O) device. It reports its completion status asynchronously, calling the specified completion routine when reading is completed or canceled and the calling thread is in an alertable wait state.

If I have understood it correctly, I can specify a routine (function?) that would get called when serial data is received. But it is the last part that confuses me: "a*nd the calling thread is in an alertable wait state*". From the documentation the application can enter an alertable wait state by calling the following functions:

> An application uses the **MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx**, **WaitForSingleObjectEx**, **WaitForMultipleObjectsEx**, and **SleepEx** functions to enter an alertable wait state.

Based on this I have the following code in my MFC application:

```
CSerialPort arduino;
OVERLAPPED overlapped{};
HANDLE hEvent = nullptr;
char command_Arduino[1];


void CTAB1::OnBnClickedButton()
{
    hEvent = CreateEvent(nullptr, TRUE, FALSE, nullptr);
    ATLASSERT(hEvent != nullptr);
    overlapped.hEvent = hEvent;
    arduino.SetMask(EV_RXCHAR);
    arduino.ReadEx(command_Arduino, 1, &overlapped, Run);
    WaitForSingleObjectEx(hEvent, INFINITE, TRUE);
}
```

However this gives me an unhandled exception:

> 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000.

Where am I going wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** Thanks to all the helpful comments, I was able to achieve asynchronous serial receive in a separate worker thread.

Declarations and definitions:

```
#define WM_USER1 (WM_USER + 1)

CSerialPort arduino;
HANDLE WorkerThread = nullptr;

DWORD WINAPI SerialInputMotorControl_Thread(LPVOID WndPtr);
LRESULT CTAB1::on_wm_user1(WPARAM, LPARAM);
```

Creating the thread:

```
void CTAB1::OnBnClickedButtonMotorRun()
{
    m_MotorRun.EnableWindow(FALSE); //Disable run button
    m_MotorStop.EnableWindow(TRUE); //Enable stop button

    //Create worker thread for dealing with serial receive
    WorkerThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, SerialInputMotorControl_Thread, (LPVOID)m_hWnd, 0, NULL); 
}
```

Terminating the thread:

```
void CTAB1::OnBnClickedButtonMotorStop()
{
    m_MotorRun.EnableWindow(TRUE);
    m_MotorStop.EnableWindow(FALSE);
    if (WorkerThread != nullptr)
    {
        if (!TerminateThread(WorkerThread, 0)) //Delete worker thread
        {
            DWORD err = GetLastError();
            MessageBox(_T("Error: %d", err), _T("ERROR"), MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
        }
    }
    else
        MessageBox(_T("Error: Thread not terminated"), _T("ERROR"), MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);

    CloseHandle(WorkerThread); //Clean-up
}
```

The thread:

```
DWORD WINAPI SerialInputMotorControl_Thread(LPVOID WndPtr)
{
    HWND hWnd = (HWND)WndPtr;
    char command_Arduino[1] = {};
    int prev_command = 100;
    while(1)
    {
        try
        {
            arduino.Read(command_Arduino, 1);
        }
        catch (CSerialException& e)
        {
            if (e.m_dwError == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
            {
                DWORD dwBytesTransferred = 0;
            }
        }
        char command;
        command = command_Arduino[0];
        
        if (prev_command != command) 
        {
            if (command < 1) {
                command = 0;
            }
            if (command > 16) {
                command = 16;
            }

            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_USER1, command, 0); //Send message to GUI
            prev_command = command;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Then handle the command in the GUI message handler.

Comment: It's bad behavior to wait indefinitely in the click event handler of a GUI component. Also, the information given in the question may not be sufficient for others to reproduce, verify, or investigate the problem. Please refer to these help articles to improve your question. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This is going to behave synchronously even if you get it working. You have probably already succeeded with reading synchronously. To make it asynchronous, see this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/68788430/4603670, you should be able use the same synchronous functions (`arduino.Read`?), put them in your own worker thread, then use `PostMessage` or `SetEvent` to signal completion.

Comment: That `WaitForSingleObjectEx()` call effectively makes the operation synchronous - the main (UI) thread will be blocked until the reading is complete. And this affects your app, it will freeze until the operation is complete. You should better put the I/O in another, worker thread (owning no windows and not creating a message-loop). Certain UI items could be disabled while the I/O is being executed, and enabled back when it is complete. You could even add a "Kill" or "Cancel" function (destroying the worker thread and I/O items and handles), if it tends to hang.

Comment: you need overwrite [`PumpMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinthread-class?view=msvc-170#pumpmessage) in mfc app and here use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` with `MWMO_ALERTABLE` if you want alertable wait and use `ReadFileEx`. or you can bind your file to IOCP and use `ReadFile` . in both case you not need use  `hEvent` in `OVERLAPPED`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani can I have the worker thread run for the entire time the application runs, or is this bad practice/dangerous? I want the serial communication to receive some data, perform some processing on this data and send out a command to some other external hardware, and this is completely independent of the UI (apart from buttons to start/stop listening to the serial input - which I assume I would have to code to create/terminate the worker thread). I currently have the function to process the data in the UI thread but can I move it all to the worker thread?

Comment: Yes, you can do that for example if device is constantly running and updating GUI. It's not bad practice, but it can be dangerous depending on implementation. Make sure the two thread don't share any variables, they can pass copy of data to each other, communicate using `PostMessage`/`SetEvent` or other thread synchronization objects/methods.